# "mvc:annotation-driven" crashes the program

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, annotations

My program (Java 6, Spring 3.2.4.) works just fine, but when I add "mvc:annotation-driven" to my Spring XML it crashes. I need Hibernate Validator so I need that command. I wonder though why my other annotations (@RequestMapping, @Controller etc.) are working.

Spring-base.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="testing" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/Jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Console says:

```
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:238)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:205)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:123)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.
java:235)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

When I stop the server (Glassfish 4.0) and debug: nothing.

When I clean and build:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-
clean) on project ProjectDB: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users 
\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjectDB\target\ProjectDB-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF
\lib\spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar -> [Help 1]
```

I don't get what is going on.

Comment: You're missing the `mvc` namespace declarations.

Comment: Thanks! Working now, damn these noobie mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:238)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:205)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:123)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:235)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)